# how to edit and insert data from the single form

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my controller. Here the function `add_post()` is the function that is used in both adding and updating data. The problem is that if I want to edit the form then I can get the value from the database into the form of respective area but when I want to add the data using the same function I cannot. I searched a lot but could not find the solution.

```
    <?php
    class Blog_controller extends CI_Controller {

        public function index() {
            $this->get_post();
        }

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->helper('url'); 
            $this->load->model('blog_model');
        }

        function add_post($id) {
            if($id==NULL) {
                return $this->load->view('admin/add_post');
            } else {
                $data['query']=$this->blog_model->get_single_post($id);
                $this->load->view('admin/add_post',$data);
            }
        }

        function do_upload() {
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '100';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->load->view('premium/main', $error);
            } else {
                $this->upload->do_upload();
                $data=$this->upload->data();
                $filename=$data['file_name'];
                $this->blog_model->insert_post($filename);
            }
        }

        function get_post() {
            $data['query']=$this->blog_model->get_post();
            $this->load->view('premium/main',$data);
        }

        function view_table() {
            $data['query']=$this->blog_model->get_post(); $this->load->view('admin/view_table',$data);
        }   
    }
    ?>



MODEL
```

This is the model of my project.. I want to insert and update the data using the single function i.e. insert_post().

```
    <?php 
Class Blog_model extends CI_Model
{

function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
$this->load->database();
}




 function insert_post($filename)
 {
 $data=array(
 'title'=>$this->input->post('title'),
'description'=>$this->input->post('description'),
'publish'=>$this->input->post('publish'),
'image'=>$filename,
);

$this->db->insert('post',$data);
 redirect('blog_controller');

}


function get_post()
{
$query = $this->db->get_where('post');
return $query->result();
}
function get_single_post($id)
{
$query = $this->db->get_where('post',array('id'=>$id));
return $query->row($id);
}
}
?>
```

This is my view. In this form i want to add the data when the user wants to insert data and when user wants to edit then the data should be retrived in the respective field of the form and should be updated...

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>Add Blog Title</h1>
    <?php function add_post($id);?>
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('blog_controller/do_upload');?>
    <p>Title : <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php if($id==0){echo $query->title;}?>"></br></p>
    <p>Description : <textarea name="description" rows="5"> <?php echo $query->title;?></textarea></br/></p>
    <p>Current Image : <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/uploads/<?php echo $query->image;?>"</b></p>
    <p>Image : <?php echo form_upload('userfile');?></b></p>
    <p>Publish ?: <input type="checkbox" name="publish" value="1" <?php if($query->publish == 1) echo 'checked="checked"';?>></br></p>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"> 

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is my table from which the respective editing field id is passed so we can view data in the form and can know which field of which data we want to edit ..

```
<html>
<body>

<table border="2px">

<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>Title</td>
<td>Description</td>
<td>image</td>
<td>Action</td>
</tr>
<?php foreach($query as $a):?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $a->id;?></td>
<td><?php echo $a->title;?></td>
<td><?php echo $a->description;?></td>
<td><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/uploads/<?php echo $a->image?>" height="100px" width="100px"></td>
<td><?php echo anchor('blog_controller/add_post/'.$a->id,"Edit");?></td>
<td><?php echo anchor('blog_controler/delete_post/'.$a->id,"Delete");?></td>

<?php endforeach;?>
</tr>




</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you use `return` here? `return $this->load->view('admin/add_post');`

Comment: Do you want to create edit method in your controller to gett the data for already created post and "reload" these values into your "edit" form in admin?

Comment: I think there are 2 possible options: 1. your $id is always null 2. the data you get from the database using $id is empty. Can you please those 2 options?

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate the form data sent to controller and then send these values back to the view: here is an example:

```
function add_post() 
{
   if ($this->input->post())
   {
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Text', 'trim|required|min_length[8]');
   }

   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
      // VALIDATION ERROR
   }
   else 
   {
      // SUCCESS
      // code to save title in db ...
      // and redirect to success page
      redirect('admin/posts');
   ]

   $this->load->view('admin/add_post', $data);


}
```

So, it will reload the view if it'n nothing sent in text field and min lenght is not at least 8 characters.

If it's ok, the code in this part is exectued (you will need your own save to db function there, now I haven't add it there) and redirected to admin/posts.

And in your form instead of:

```
<input type="text" name="text" value=""/>
```

you need to dome thing such as:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('text'); ?>"/>
```

Comment: I think You did'nt understand my question . I just want to add and update the data of the database from the single form i.e. one function of the controller that can do these works at a time...

Comment: Put your model in your question, so everybody can see it.

Comment: Man, half of that stuff should be in controller, especially for `insert` . Put in your model only things like `$this->db->insert('post',$data);`